# Unity 2D - Attack system only works while moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I've recently started coding on Unity, trying to make a game. So long it's been fine, but I faced a problem.
I've implemented a script for the Attack System:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AttackDamage : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float attackDamage = 20;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) 
    { 
        if (other.GetComponent<Health>() != null)
        {
            Health health = other.GetComponent<Health>();
            health.TakeDamage(attackDamage);
        }
    }
}
```

And I also implemented one for the Health System:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Health : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image healthBar;
    public float healthAmount = 100;

    private void Update() 
    {
        if (healthAmount <= 0)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
        }
    }

    public void TakeDamage(float Damage)
    {
        healthAmount -= Damage;

        healthBar.fillAmount = healthAmount / 100;
    }

    public void Healing(float healPoints)
    {
        healthAmount += healPoints;
        healthAmount = Mathf.Clamp(healthAmount, 0, 100);

        healthBar.fillAmount = healthAmount / 100;
    }
}
```

And it works prety well.
But as you read on the title, the attack only actually works right after I move. If I try to attack while I'm not moving, the attackArea appears on the scene, but doesn't deal damage. And i can't figure out why.

Do you have any idea on what could be the problem?

Here there's also a video of what actually happens, in the game:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BTYTNz_yzus-eRLnjsgB0hsYLU5sQm2k?usp=sharing

I have no idea on how to solve this problem, since I've copied the code from a source online, which actually works prorperly.

The code is exactly the same, apart form the script for the Health System, which is not shown on the video, but which also shouldn't make that much of a difference.

So i really don't know how to handle this.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You may need to have a look at `OnTriggerStay2D` and `OnTriggerExit2D` messages.

Comment: I don't see the `AttackDamage` script attached to the `AttackArea` gameobject. I suspect that you've put it on the character, which would mean that instead of the attack dealing damage it is actually the characters collider and rb entering the other characters trigger.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to deal continuous damage while any health-character is in the trigger, use [`OnTriggerStay2d`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay2D.html) instead.

---

Otherwise, if you are looking to deal damage when the user presses a button, you can do the following:

1. Have a hit-box collider that stores all enemy in range. (By adding enemy to a list when it enters the hit-box, and removing them from list when they exit.)
2. When the attack is triggered, fetch all enemy in the list from `1.` and deal damage to all.

Code-wise, looks something like this:

```
public class AttackDamage : MonoBehaviour
{
    private HashSet<Health> inRange = new HashSet<Health>();    

    private float attackDamage = 20;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) 
    { 
        if (other.GetComponent<Health>() != null) 
        {
            // Add to set of characters that are in range of attack
            inRange.Add(other.GetComponent<Health>());
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        var charHealth = other.GetComponent<Health>();
        if (charHealth != null) {
            // Remove, since it exit the range of the attacking character.
            inRange.Remove(charHealth);
        }
    }

    // Call this function whenever you want to do damage to all characters in range.
    public void Attack(){
        foreach(var character in inRange){
            character.TakeDamage(attackDamage);
        }
    }
}
```

Then somewhere else... (example, in your player.)

```
public class YourPlayer {
    // ...
 
    // Inspector reference to the hitbox
    [SerializeField]
    private AttackDamage attackHitbox;

    private void Update(){
        // Attack when button is pressed (or something).
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) {
             attackHitbox.Attack();
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

Finally, if you are looking to deal damage at specific points in an animation, the term you should search for is *Key-Frame*. Look for a tutorial on *Animation*, then *Key-Frame*.

Once you learn about it, you can use the above mentioned method, but call the damage script on your desired key-frames.